# Cannot submit Spark app to cluster, stuck on "UNDEFINED"

Tags: apache-spark

I use this command to summit **spark application** to **yarn cluster**

```
export YARN_CONF_DIR=conf
bin/spark-submit --class "Mining"
  --master yarn-cluster
  --executor-memory 512m ./target/scala-2.10/mining-assembly-0.1.jar
```

**In Web UI, it stuck on** `UNDEFINED`

[image]

**In console, it stuck to**

```
<code>14/11/12 16:37:55 INFO yarn.Client: Application report from ASM: 
     application identifier: application_1415704754709_0017
     appId: 17
     clientToAMToken: null
     appDiagnostics: 
     appMasterHost: example.com
     appQueue: default
     appMasterRpcPort: 0
     appStartTime: 1415784586000
     yarnAppState: RUNNING
     distributedFinalState: UNDEFINED
     appTrackingUrl: http://example.com:8088/proxy/application_1415704754709_0017/
     appUser: rain
</code>
```

#### Update:

Dive into `Logs for container` in Web UI `http://example.com:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1415704754709_0017_01_000001/rain/stderr/?start=0`, I found this

```
14/11/12 02:11:47 WARN YarnClusterScheduler: Initial job has not accepted 
any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered
and have sufficient memory
14/11/12 02:11:47 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (1211012646) connection to
spark.mvs.vn/192.168.64.142:8030 from rain sending #24418
14/11/12 02:11:47 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (1211012646) connection to
spark.mvs.vn/192.168.64.142:8030 from rain got value #24418
```

I found this problem have had solution here http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-apache-spark-hdp/

```
The Hadoop cluster must have sufficient memory for the request.

For example, submitting the following job with 1GB memory allocated for
executor and Spark driver fails with the above error in the HDP 2.1 Sandbox.
Reduce the memory asked for the executor and the Spark driver to 512m and
re-start the cluster.
```

I'm trying this solution and hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solutions

Finally I found that `it caused by memory problem`

It worked when I change `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` to `3072` (its value was 2048) in Web UI of interface and restarted cluster.

[image]

I'm very happy to see this

[image]

With 3GB in yarn nodemanager, my summit is

```
bin/spark-submit
    --class "Mining"
    --master yarn-cluster
    --executor-memory 512m
    --driver-memory 512m
    --num-executors 2
    --executor-cores 1
    ./target/scala-2.10/mining-assembly-0.1.jar`
```

Comment: Yes, this is a memory problem for sure. However, you bumped up the overall memory available for containers. I notice that you were only requesting for 512m each for driver and executors (x 2). That is still below the original 2048m you had set for yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb, or did you have more YARN apps running on this node?

Comment: No, I'm surely that I don't run other apps on this node.